# $K[X]=K(X)$ with X set of algebraic elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ an extension field of $K$ and $X$ a subset of algebraic elements of $F$ over $K$, $K(X)$ the intersections of all fields containing $K$ and $X$, and $K[X]$ the intersections of all rings containing $K$ and $X$.

Is it $K(X)=K[X]$?

In case $X$ is finite, I can prove it with induction starting from $K(a)=K[a]$ with $a$ algebraic (this result is in textbooks) then my question is for X infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because every element of $K(X)$ belongs to $K(Y)$ where $Y$ is a finite subset of $X$:
$$
K(X)
= \bigcup_{\substack{Y \subseteq X \\ Y \text{ finite}}} K(Y)
= \bigcup_{\substack{Y \subseteq X \\ Y \text{ finite}}} K[Y]
= K[X]
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I was thinking that your proof can be used also in finite and infinite case in this way:

$$K(X)
= \bigcup_{\substack{a \in X }} K(a)
= \bigcup_{\substack{a \in X }} K[a]
= K[X]
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: @asv, not directly, because your first equality is not clear. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: I was thinking that  $K(X)=\{f(a)g(a)^{-1}|a \in X, f(x),g(x) \in K[x], g \neq 0\}$ but it is not. It occurs if X={a}. Then we must prove first the finite case and then the infinite case with your proof. If I'm not wrong